# Firebase Storage ссылки на картинки

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, storage

Решил закинуть все изображения в Firebase Storage. Так вот у меня в приложении используется карточки с картинками которые грузятся по ссылке в Firebase. Возник вопрос если я выложу приложение и его скачают очень много пользователей и буду обращаться к этим картинкам Приложение не будет тормозить? или сам Firebase не может меня заблокировать так как  у меня бесплатный аккаунт а обращение к Storage очень большое?

Comment: Проблемы по нагрузке берет на себя Firebase, так что тормозов со стороны Firebase  не будет. Когда будет исчерпана бесплатная квота, то Firebase больше не будет отправлять изображения, и нужно будет перейти на другой план. На что нужно обратить внимание- я заметил что бесплатная квота на месяц, так же поделена по дням, то есть  в день можно использовать 1/30 месячной квоты. НО ЭТО НЕ ТОЧНО !

Comment: А вообще что рационально использовать в плане сервера для картинок, может быть ссылку в вк делать

Comment: Я использую хостинг для "адаптивных" картинок, то есть сервер автоматом уменьшает картинку под размер экрана юзера - как следствие быстродействие, и меньше трафика. Firebase так не может. Про вк не знаю, в некоторых странах он заблокирован, но как плюс - это бесплатно, как минус - блокировки, не адаптивно, а если фото удалят или изменят...

Comment: а что за хостинг?

Comment: https://uploadcare.com/ - их много, но я выбрал этот, потому что только тут я смог открыть прайс лист и увидеть сколько я буду платить и за что. Ну и к тому же -  условия норм.

Comment: ок, спасибо  большое